# Error creating bean with name 'expertiseRepository': Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following Query.

```
public interface ExpertiseRepository extends JpaRepository<Expertise, Long>{

@Query("SELECT em.name FROM project.employee em join project.expertise ex WHERE em.id = ex.employee_id AND ex.gain_date = ?1")
public List<Employee> getEmployeesByGainDate(String gainDate);
```

}

But I'm getting this error.

```
Error creating bean with name 'expertiseRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List
```

What I'm I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: "FROM project.employee" should be not schema.table_name but entity name

Comment: thank you! that was the mistake. Here is the final query that works for me:

public interface ExpertiseRepository extends JpaRepository<Expertise, Long>{
 
 @Query("SELECT em FROM Employee em, Expertise ex WHERE em.id = ex.employee AND ex.gainDate = ?1")
 public List<Employee> getEmployeesByGainDate(String gainDate);

}